# System not booting after resizing /dev/sda2 and creating a swap partition

Tags: arch-linux, boot, devices, swap, fsck

Error Message:

> dev/sda2: The filesystem size (according to the super) is 31126889 blocks
> The physical size of the device is 29884416 blocks
> Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
>
> dev/sda2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
> (i.e., without -a or -p options)
> ERROR: Bailing out. Run 'fsck UUID=a917670a-45bf-4650-817f-fa69878a349a' manually
> FILESYSTEM CHECK FAILED.
> Please run fsck manually. After leaving
> this maintenance shell, the system will
> reboot automatically.

Additional information:

I did run fsck on /dev/sda2 and ignored all the errors and it did say FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED but nothing seems to happen i rebooted the computer and it did not work. I am using archcraft arch based distribution

Thank you.

Comment: stop any action: you are at risk of losing (more) data. You should boot with a rescue image and do a complete (block) backup of your current disk before proceeding any further. Anyway with fsck done (+ swap signature written to) damage is already done

Comment: Yeah its looks like i don't really have a choice i will have install the whole system again well the good thing is at least the data was not that important to me, Thank you.

Comment: Next time: before shrinking the partition, the filesystem has to be shrunk. For this the filesystem must have such feature. Example: XFS can't (yet), Ext4 can but only offline (meaning: booting on a live image is probable needed too) etc.

Comment: Next time i will keep that in mind and do more research before doing anything like this again, Thanks again for all the information.

Comment: Btw, I didn't read correctly. If you ignored all questions, maybe not so much damage was done. Once a backup is done, reverting to previous state (remove swap partition, restore previous partition size) and again a fsck, would probably recover most of it, except the part were swap wrote data and corrupted previous data, but you wouldn't know exactly where corruption happened.

Comment: Ahh its not important data and i did have the feeling that this is gonna destroy my system I did not listen to the feeling and now i have to pay the price

Comment: Run `resize2fs /dev/sda` - that should fix the issue.

Comment: Yeah I already tried that and it said command not found,  thank you

Comment: Next time, or possibly this time, use the [GParted Live CD/USB](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) which contains the tool @ArtemS.Tashkinov was referring to, and allows the offline modification A.B is referring to.  In this instance offline means all the HDD's and SDD's that your OS use to boot are not booted from your OS.  The LiveCD can then detect the disk for modification without interference from your OS.